# MariaDB Cluster Cannot Join new Node

Tags: galera, mariadb-10.1

This is status on Main node. it's show some seqno as 17210843
[image]

when new empty node is join. i'm found rsync process is ok. but i see difference seqno in linux process 
[image]
after finish this process my new node cannot join 
and grastat.dat is zero uuid and service mysql on new node fail to start
[image]

i'm try to re-step again by manual edit 
uuid to same Main node 
seqno :-1 
saafe_to_bootstrap : 0
and restart service mysql in new node
after new node try to sync.
service mysql on new node is fail again like this step (seqno dose not same between main node and new node)

how can i do with this problem